# aspnetcore.identity - in role, but getting denied access

Tags: security, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

Core 2.0, using AspnetCore.Identity. I created a few roles, including "Admin".

```
    //initializing custom roles 
    var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Training", "Operations", "Membership", "Individual" };
    IdentityResult roleResult;

    foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
    {
        var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
        // ensure that the role does not exist
        if (!roleExist)
        {
            //create the roles and seed them to the database: 
            roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName)); 
        }
    }
```

I checked the SQL tables, and they're all there.:

[image]

Then I add myself to the Admin role (not the full method, but the relevant parts):

```
    var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var _eric = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("username@gmail.com");
        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(_eric, "Admin");
```

I check the tables, and I'm in there (along with another guy I added to a different role):

[image]

I then travel over to my method and slap Authorize on it with two of the roles, one of which I'm in (Admin):

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Training, Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{



    return View();
}
```

And then I get **access denied**. I'm missing something, but can't figure out what step I messed up. User is in there, I'm logged in, the data tables show me as having the role assigned, and the Authorize tag looks good.

Comment: Just curious... did you signin before accessing the route?

Comment: Also, trying removing the space character before the Admin role

Comment: @SamiAl90, yep, logged in while trying to access. Matt,  I chopped it down to just "Admin", took the "Training, Admin" out. Still no dice.

Comment: @Eric did u ever solve this i am having the same , i am signing out the user to ensure they are fresh but still access denied

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Roles are claims and claims are loaded only on sign in. If you modify a claim (such as by adding a role), you must sign the user out and either automatically sign them back in or prompt the user to re-authenticate, to reload the claims.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, for saving me from punching my monitor. I logged out / logged in, and it works as expected.

Comment: Man I was hoping this worked. I've got the same exact thing. Using AzureAD. I created a group and I'm pretty sure that's the same thing as the role but maybe not. Because if I use the `[Authorize]` attribute it works, but if I `[Authorize(Role = "group)]` I get access denied.

Comment: `automatically sign them back in` this sounds like a good idea. How do we do it?

Comment: Inject a `SignInManager<TUser>` and call `SignInAsync`

Comment: one thing you can do to make this work as expected after closing the browser window and re-opening is changing the isPersistent property to true on the Register and ExternalLogin pages `_signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);` by default it's false.